# How to call the generalization of arc length obtained by considering chains in metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, terminology

Consider a [metric space $(M, d)$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_space#Definition) and a [totally ordered set (chain) $X \subset M$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order)
where $a \in M$ is "the initiating element with respect to chain $X$" in the sense that

- either $a \in X$ is the first element of chain $X$, i.e. $y \in X \implies a \leq y$,
- or else $a \notin X$;

and where $b \in M$ is "the concluding element with respect to chain $X$" in the sense that

- either $b \in X$ is the last element of chain $X$, i.e. $y \in X \implies y \leq b$,
  in which case necessarily $b ~~/ \! \! \! \! \! \! \equiv a$,
- or else $b \notin X$, in which case $b$ is not necessarily distinct from $a$.

Note that such a chain $X$ (with "the terminating elements $a$, $b$" added if appropriate)
is **not necessarily a [curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve#Definition)** (in the sense of "curve" as an image of a continuous function from a suitable interval of real numbers into the given metric space):
neither is the order topology (as the one obvious topology) of chain $X$ necessarily [homeomorphic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Homeomorphisms) to an interval;
nor are "metric gaps" excluded (in a sense which is explicated below) thus possibly spoiling ["epsilon-delta" evaluation of continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function#Weierstrass_and_Jordan_definitions_.28epsilon.E2.80.93delta.29_of_continuous_functions).

For any particular $n$-element subset $$P_n \equiv \{ p_k \}_n \subset ((X \cup \{ a, b\}) \setminus \{a, b\})$$ the "$(n + 1)$-segment sum"

$$d[~a, p_1~] + \left( \sum_{k = 1}^{n - 1} d[~p_k, p_{(k + 1)}~] \right) + d[~p_n, b~] := s[~P_n~]$$

may be evaluated (where the expression on the right-hand side has been introduced as a mere abbreviation).

For the class $\mathscr P_n$ of all possible such $n$-element subsets of chain $X$ the [supremum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infimum_and_supremum) of all corresponding "$(n + 1)$-segment sum" values may be evaluated:

$${\text{sup}}_{(\mathscr P_n)}\big\{ P_n \in \mathscr P_n : s[~P_n~] \big\} := \sigma_n[~X_a^b~]$$

(again introducing a descriptive abbreviation on the right-hand side).

Finally, the supremum over all natural numbers $n \in \mathbb N$ may be evaluated:

$${\text{sup}}_{(\mathbb N)}\big\{ n \in \mathbb N : \sigma_n[~X_a^b~] \big\} := \ell_d[~X_a^b~]$$

(where the right-hand side abbreviation aims to display all parameters which were relevant for the evaluation).

(The notion of possible "metric gaps" mentioned above relates to evaluating such "$\ell$"-values for subchains of chain $X$, too, and determining their convergence and continuity or discontinuity with respect to the order topology of $X$.)

**My question:**

How to call the value $\ell_d[~X_a^b~]$, which is obtained as described for the given chain $X$ (with "the terminating elements $a$, $b$" added if appropriate), referring to the metric $d$ ?

Is it usual terminology to call it "arc length", even though the Wikipedia definitions on ["arc"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_(geometry)) and hence on ["arc length"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arc_length) seem to be concerned explicitly and only with curves, and therefore not with the general case described above
?

Or is it perhaps appropriate or even usual terminology to call it "chain length" ?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Riemann-Stieltjes integral?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann–Stieltjes_integral

Comment: @rschwieb: "_Are you familiar with the Riemann-Stieltjes integral?_" -- Enough to notice certain relations to the example laid out in my question. But to which answer does this lead? Are you suggesting to call the quantity under consideration, $\ell_d[~X_a^b~]$, "the (R-S) integral, from $a$ to $b$, via chain $X$ (of weight 1)", for instance; and perhaps "chain integral" for short? If so (or similar), please consider expanding this into an answer. (But note that the Wikipedia [line integral](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral) again is restricted to "evaluation along a curve".)

Comment: p.s. Please note my recent **Edit**, which treats element $a \in M$ explicitly as "the initiating element with respect to chain $X$"; in more symmetric correspondence to element $b \in M$ being "the concluding element with respect to chain $X$". (This should be considered a merely formal improvement; my actual question stands as before.)

Comment: Honestly the question was a bit TL;DR for me, but I hoped you could make a rapid comparison of the two to see if it helps. That's what this reminded me of. I'm not sure there is a real connection. Good luck